# App cannot see module's activities

Tags: android, import, module, gradle, android-studio

I'm working with Android Studio.

I have working application "AppForAdd", that I want to include to another app "ExampleApp" as a module.

"AppForAdd" is using some modules and libraries.

"ExampleApp" is very simple app, that has only one button for opening "AppForAdd" module.

What I've already did:

- -> Created "ExampleApp";
- -> Added "AppForAdd" as a module and modules/libraries that are needed to "AppForAdd";
- -> Tried to compile - success;

Now I am trying to make "AppForAdd" actually work in "ExampleApp", so I've added dependency "compile project(':AppForAddModule')". Then compiled - success. Then I was trying to import class to "ExampleApp.MainActivity" by adding this "import com.appforadd.launch.Loader". But unfortunately Android Studio IDE says that "cannot resolve symbol 'Loader'". If I delete ".Loader", then it says "cannot resolve symbol 'launch'". In other words "ExampleApp" cannot see module. I don't know what I miss and what to do to solve this problem, maybe you can give some suggestions?

Thank you.

I hope that you will understand my problem, but if not, please ask.

P.S. It is very strange because:

- List item when I am starting to type "import com.*" in ExampleApp.MainActivity, Android Studio suggests only "com.exampleapp.*"
- List item when I am starting to type "import com.*" in AppForAdd.MainActivity, Android Studio suggests a lot of suggestions

Looks like that ExampleApp and AppForAdd are living completely different lives.

Comment: Which version of Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Android Studio 0.4.3. Many bugs related to this were fixed in that version.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution by making AppForAdd as android-library in build.gradle apply plugin: 'android-library'